# Modify cell range color based on value of one cell

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I'm using a userform to populate cells in a spreadsheet, but I can't figure out how to change the background color of the cells in the populated row based on the value in one of those cells. I'm pretty new to the VBA thing, so bear with me. Here is my userform code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub Insert_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Sheet1.Activate

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Category.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Dt_Initiated.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Due_Date.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Requestor.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Assigned_To.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Status.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Description.Value

Unload Me


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Category
    .AddItem "Chaplain"
    .AddItem "Jag"
    .AddItem "Medical"
    .AddItem "Personnel"
    .AddItem "Red Cross"
    .AddItem "Misc"
End With

With Status
    .AddItem "Initiated"
    .AddItem "Pending"
    .AddItem "Complete"
End With

End Sub
```

This all works as intended without any issues. Now I need it to change to background color of the row based on the status. I've tried searching and using different code with no luck.

Help?

Comment: Based on what do you need to change the color? I would suggest to look at [conditional formatting](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format1_2010.php) to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can look to Conditional Formatting, and see if that will help you out.  That can be more straightforward than VBA.  Having said that, here's a quick sketch of how you can set a color for a cell.  (PS: What's `Status` declared as in your code, a range yeah?).

```
Sub testColors()
Dim myRow as Integer
Dim Status as String, celStatus as String
Dim rng as Range, cel as Range

Status = "Confirmed!" ' some string you want to find matches for

Set rng = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(100,1)) ' Equivalent to Range("A1:A100")
For each cel in rng
  if cel.value = Status then
      cel.entireRow.interior.colorindex = 6
  End if
next cel
End Sub
```

So, if you want to set the color of the row based on status, you could do something like the following:

```
...
For each cel in rng
 Select case cel.Value
  case "Color yellow!"
     cel.entireRow.interior.colorindex = 6
  case "Color green!"
     cel.entireRow.interior.colorindex = 4
 ...etc, etc.
End select
next cel
```

This will loop through your range, and if the cell value is `Color yellow!`, it will color the cell yellow.  See [here for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx) a quick summary of `colorIndex`.

Again, I might look into conditional formatting first to see if that would work - conditional formatting would change the cell colors dynamically, if you manually change the cells, without having to run a macro.  If there'd be a lot of conditions to set, maybe look in to doing Conditional Formatting, but with VBA as part of your code? Just a thought.

Comment: Status seems to be a ComboBox just like Category

Comment: @DragonSamu ah - I'm not too familiar with ComboBoxes, I hope the above ideas will still work though - they should, no?

Comment: If the code is put in a Module and not inside the Userform it will not conflict. As outside the UserForm you need to refer as UserForm1.Status.Value etc..

Answer (score 0):

This will color all your rows depending on the value in coloumn 7:

```
Sub Macro2()
'


'

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To emptyRow
If Cells(i, 7).Value = "Pending" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    End If

    If Cells(i, 7).Value = "Initiated" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Interior.ColorIndex = 7

    End If
    If Cells(i, 7).Value = "Complete" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Interior.ColorIndex = 8

    End If
  Next i


End Sub
```